# Connector c++ res->getBoolean Acess Violation

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql-connector, connector

I am using the `mysql-connector-c++-1.1.4-winx64` in `Visual Studio 2013`.
Connecting to a specific database and reading out Integer values works however it is impossible to retrieve any boolean value.
I can compile the program including the attached code but the program closes retrieving:

> "The program '[3480] Project1.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited
>   with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'."

I appreciate any help!

```
                                    const char* idQuery = "SELECT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM experiment_results WHERE id='22');";
                                    stmt = con->createStatement();
                                    stmt->execute(idQuery);
                                    while (res->next()) 
                                    {
                                        bool flag = res->getBoolean(1);
                                    }
```

Comment: they query is empty. Double check it and you'll find that probably trying to access null data.

Comment: May I need some further explanation about this. Shouldn´t "SELECT EXISTS(Query)", independent of the return value of "Query", always retrieve true or false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking again at the code I notice my mistake:
stmt->execute(idQuery); // Should be: 
res = stmt->executeQuery(idQuery);